# chrome browser shows counting error for nodejs code

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, counting

I wrote some nodejs code. In execution, I noticed that the chrome browser for the first visit shows the count with value 1 then for the visit after, it shows 3, 5, 9 and so on. the Internet explorer browser works fine, I mean, it shows 1, 2, 3 and so on. I don't understand the reason of it. The code I wrote is attached below. Where is the mistake in my code?

Thanks for any help.

```
var http = require('http');
var socket = require('socket.io')();
var port = process.env.port || 1337;
var count = 0;
var x = 0;
socket.on('connection', function (client) {
    count++;
    console.log("soc con");
    client.broadcast({ count: count })
    client.on('disconnect', function () {
        count--;
        console.log("soc dis");
    });
    console.log(count);
})

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    count++;
    var c = count.toString();
    res.end(c);
}).listen(port);
```

Comment: Your code looks a bit confused.  You show a plain vanilla web server running on `process.env.port || 1337;`.  It does `count++` in every incoming http request.  Then, you also show a socket.io server with `require('socket.io')();` that doesn't appear to be attached to your web server.  Is there something missing from your code?

Comment: I'm  a new one in nodejs programming. it's what I wrote and execute  using internet explore browser and  it worked fine. but using chrome browser didn't.

Comment: Is the code you have in your question really your exact code?  It does not like it to me.  Your http server and your socket.io server would not be sharing the same server and would not be on the same port.

Comment: I comment the socket block of code and change port declaration to var port = 1337; and still counting 1,3,5,7...

Comment: See my answer below, now that you've removed the socket.io code from the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When browsers connect to a web page, they will often request the page you ask for AND they will request the icon for the page (called the favicon).  That's two requests to the same server.  If you add:

```
console.log(req.url);
```

to your server handler, you will see that you are getting two requests for each browser page, one for the URL of the page and one for a page icon (often called the favicon).  If you want to ignore the page icon request, you can add an `if` block like this `if (req.url === "/") { code here}` to avoid any other URL requests and only increment your counter for specific pages.

How exactly the page icon is requested is browser-specific so it is certainly possible that IE might behave differently than Chrome in this case.

Change your server to this:

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    if (req.url === '/') {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
        count++;
        res.end(count);
    } else {
        res.statusCode = 404;
        res.end();
    }
}).listen(port);
```

---

FYI, you can replace this:

```
var c = count.toString();
res.end(c);
```

with this:

```
res.end(count);
```

In Javascript, string conversions happen automatically.

Comment: I put the `if (req.url === "/"){  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    count++;
    var c = count.toString();
    res.end(c); }` and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: @jfriend00 You say that if I do `console.log(req.url)` I would see 2 requests but I don't see them, I just see `/`. Can you explain that.  Here is what I have `app.get("/", (req, res) =>{
 console.log(req.url)
 res.end()
})` I tested in FF and Chrome.

Comment: @jackblank - `app.get("/", ...)` already filtered things down to only a single route request for only the `"/"` route.  The OP was using a generic http request handler (not an Express route) that saw ALL http requests to that server (no filtering).  Your `app.get("/", ...)` handler only sees requests for the `"/"` URL so it won't see the favicon URL request which is a different route.  If you made a specific route for the favicon request, you would see that get hit (if the browser didn't already have the favicon cached).

Answer (score 0):

Your count is doubling up because you increment `count` in both your server middleware

```
function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
  //here
  count++;
  var c = count.toString();
  res.end(c);
})
```

and your socket connection

```
socket.on('connection', function (client) {
  //here
  count++;
  console.log("soc con");
  client.broadcast({ count: count })
  client.on('disconnect', function () {
    count--;
    console.log("soc dis");
  });
  console.log(count);
})
```

So every time you open a new tab/window, your count increments twice. I am not sure why this would change based on the browser you're using, unfortunately.

Comment: I comment the socket block of code and still counting 1,3,5 and so on.